# Is there a technical restriction that won't allow Periscope to use a HTML5 video player?

Tags: html, flash, video-streaming

I can't watch Periscope without flash:

[image: flash required]

Since Periscope is pretty new and hype I find it a pity flash is required. My best guess then is that they simply **can't**.

But what is the technical restriction if one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say for sure about their own technical restrictions but they are serving the video in chunks of **.ts** files. It is **not impossible** for HTML5-based player to handle MPEG-TS streams so I can only assume this is a temporary solution.

Example of an HTML5 player handling **.ts** format is [THEOPlayer](https://www.theoplayer.com/demo). Also DailyMotion released an open-source JavaScript [HLS streaming](http://engineering.dailymotion.com/introducing-hls-js/) client. If others can already do it now, Twitter will do it soon.

**Why Flash?** : 
It's an easy solution that works same on all browsers that it's installed onto so Edge, Chrome, Safari & Firefox etc so it will each give a consistent result to their user base without specific browser limitations (since it's a plugin).

**Why assume temporary?** : 
First of all as you said it's still new (growing/developing). They have a few job openings for video programmers. [This particular job opening](https://about.twitter.com/careers/positions?id=a0Dj0000004ihN3EAI&location=Boston) requires *"Ability to create an interface in HTML, CSS and JavaScript"*. They are currently using a Flash-based JW Player instead of a custom-made Twitter player. That will change in time.